# jquery countdown plugin: no countdown, only zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown

I want to create 200 divs and timer for each div.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    for(var i=0; i<200; i++)
    {
        var tag = '<div id="' + i +'" style="width:150px"></div><br/>';
        $('#rsr').append(tag);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<200; i++)
    {
    var date = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date())

        $("#"+i).countdown({until: date});
    }
    });

    function randomDate(start, end) {
        return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
    }
```

Where is a error?
Thanks.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDFLn/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are creating a date between January 1st **2012** and today, so it's always in the past. If the target date has already passed, the plugin stops at zero.

Pick for example 2013 instead:

```
var date = randomDate(new Date(2013, 0, 1), new Date())
```

You *should* fix the id problem (they shouldn't start with a number), but most browsers can cope with it easily so it's not the actual cause.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDFLn/17/

Answer (score 0):

**id** can not start with number try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    var tag = '<div id="cnt_' + i +'" style="width:150px"></div><br/>';
    $('#rsr').append(tag);
}

for(var i=0;i<200; i++)
{
var date = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date())

    $("#cnt_"+i).countdown({until: date});
}
})
```

instead of `id="'+i+'"` do `id="cnt_'+i+'"`

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this part of your code:

```
for(var i=0;i<200; i++)
{
    var date = randomDate(new Date(2012, 0, 1), new Date());
    $("#s"+i).countdown({until: date});
}
```

You cannot have `id` with numbers as starting character. And don't forget to end the lines with a semicolon `;`.